# How to step over a recursive call while debugging?

Tags: xcode, debugging, recursion, clion

I have tried in two IDEs namely Clion and Xcode and I get the same results. 
The debugger steps into isMatch function again even if I use stepOver. I've successfully used 'stepOver' in case of other functions but I'm not sure if it works the expected way for recursive calls. Can someone help me with this?

```
bool isMatch(string s, string p) {

//Base case
if(s.length() == 0 && p.length() == 0)
    return true;

else if(p[1] == '*') {
    int i = 0;
    for (; (s[i] == p[0] || p[0] == '.') && i<s.length() ; i++) {

        string temp1 = s.substr(i);
        string temp2 = !p.length()? "" : p.substr(2);
        if (isMatch(temp1, temp2))
            return true;
    }
    if( isMatch(s.substr(i), !p.length()? "" : p.substr(2) ))
        return true;
    return false;
}
else
    return (s[0] == p[0] || p[0] == '.') && isMatch(s.substr(1), p.substr(1));
```

}

Comment: If you know the next line of execution after `isMatch` you can simply put a breakpoint there and press Continue.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal, that's basically how step over already works, except by instruction rather than line. It won't help because a) assuming he started debugging `isMatch()` by setting a breakpoint on it, he'll hit that for the recursive call unless he disables it; and b) if the recursive call hits the temporary breakpoint set by "step over", it will both stop and clear the breakpoint. (If he uses a non-temporary breakpoint as you suggest, it won't be cleared, but it may still be hit by the recursive call.)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll have to debug without any breakpoints inside that particular function.